# String[] to image gets failed

Tags: c#, winforms, image, stream

I have an array of string from which I need to Draw an image in Windows forms.

I've done the following two steps:

1. converted the string array into memory stream.
2. and used the following code:

   ```
   Image image = Image.FromStream(memory stream);
   ```

But it always returns null.

Comment: Sure... but we need to know what the strings contain and how you convert them in step 1.

Comment: @Kek : used the below code to convert to memory stream: System.IO.MemoryStream mStrm = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringimage));

Comment: @L.B : image string : "1:!!!!1!1!1!!!1!1!1:!!!1".

Comment: What do you expect exactly ? How the string 1:!!!!1!1!1... is supposed to render as an image ? Image class needs a known format to convert bytes to actual image !

Comment: @Kek: What are that known formats and in what I have the string?

Comment: I don't know all known formats, but jpg, png, bitmap are some of them. If you have a .jpg file, then you can read it with File.ReadAllBytes, then create a memorystream from the byte[] and then call FromStream on that stream. This is how it is supposed to work. Here, we don't know what you are trying to achive...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21001/discussion-between-kovilpatti-c-sharper-and-kek)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get image from byte array:

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Be aware with formats. For example, Silverlight and WPF support only JPEG or PNG. Otherwise will get an exception.

Comment: I know this coding; My problem is that it returns null and I need the reason for it.? can you?

Comment: What is the source for stringimage ? Database cell or file ?

Comment: Why not use Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName) ?

Comment: Is it resource file? You need find a way to read as byte array this part.